# Shift all rows besides the first row and then add new row Google spreadsheet api Nodejs

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am using google spreadsheets api with nodejs to insert a row on the second row of one of the files.
So my idea was to create an empty row at the row2 and then add new row values.

The problem is I want to shift all the rows besides the first one, and add a new empty row in the second row keeping all the data and then adding the new obtained data to the new created empty second row.

When I execute both requests like that below:

```
 let range = "MySheetName!A2";
 let rowArr = [
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
 ];
this.insertSecondRowBlank();
this.exeGoogleBatchUpdate()
    .then(
        this.updateRowsOnSpreadsheet(range, rowArr)
    );
```

the row with values is added on the top of row2, so it is deleting the data existing there, and then it is shifting and adding the blanked row, and what I want is the opposite. I want to keep the data in row2 and just shift all the rows besides row1 and then add the new row in a blank row just created.

The functions used here:

```
async updateRowsOnSpreadsheet(range, rowArr){
    const googleSpreadSheet = await this.getSheetInstance();
    const spreadSheetValues = googleSpreadSheet.spreadsheets.values;
    const updateRows = spreadSheetValues.update({
        auth: await this.getAuth(),
        spreadsheetId:this.fileID,
        range: range,
        valueInputOption: "RAW",
        resource:{
            values: rowArr,
        }
    });
}

async insertSecondRowBlank(sheetID = "0"){
    let singleRequest =  { 
        insertDimension : {
            range : {
                sheetId : sheetID,
                dimension : "ROWS", 
                startIndex : 1,  
                endIndex : 2,
            },
            inheritFromBefore : false,
        } 
    };
    this.requests.push(singleRequest);
}

async exeGoogleBatchUpdate(){
    let requests = this.requests;
    const batchUpdateRequest = {requests:requests};
    const sheets = await this.getSheetInstance();
    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId:this.fileID,
        resource: batchUpdateRequest,
    },(err, response) => {
        if (err) {
        } else {
        }
    });
}
```

What should I do to make google accept the first request first and then accept the second request in order? Because when I send, it is executing then `updateRowsOnSpreadsheet` first and then executing the `insertSecondRowBlank` even if the order I send is the opposite of that.

Comment: Can I ask you about the value of `range` of `this.updateRowsOnSpreadsheet(range, rowArr)`?

Comment: Sure, the range is : ```let range = "MySheetName!A2";``` and the rowArr: ```let rowArr = [
            [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 
];```

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the methods of googleapis for Node.js return Promise. In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
async updateRowsOnSpreadsheet(range, rowArr) {
  const googleSpreadSheet = await this.getSheetInstance();
  const spreadSheetValues = googleSpreadSheet.spreadsheets.values;
  const updateRows = await spreadSheetValues.update({
    auth: await this.getAuth(),
    spreadsheetId: this.fileID,
    range: range,
    valueInputOption: "RAW",
    resource: {
      values: rowArr,
    },
  });
  return updateRows;
}

insertSecondRowBlank(sheetID = "0") {
  let singleRequest = {
    insertDimension: {
      range: {
        sheetId: sheetID,
        dimension: "ROWS",
        startIndex: 1,
        endIndex: 2,
      },
      inheritFromBefore: false,
    },
  };
  this.requests.push(singleRequest);
}

async exeGoogleBatchUpdate() {
  let requests = this.requests;
  const batchUpdateRequest = { requests: requests };
  const sheets = await this.getSheetInstance();
  const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: this.fileID,
    resource: batchUpdateRequest,
  });
  return res;
}
```

In the above modified script, please modify the script for executing these functions as follows.

```js
// Please modify the function name from `run` to your actual function name.
async run() {

  // Please declare "sheetName".

  let range = sheetName + "!A2";
  let rowArr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]];
  this.insertSecondRowBlank();
  const res1 = await this.exeGoogleBatchUpdate();
  const res2 = await this.updateRowsOnSpreadsheet(range, rowArr);
  console.log(res1.data);
  console.log(res2.data);
}
```

- When I tested this, I confirmed that after a new row was inserted to the 2nd row, the value of `rowArr` was put to the inserted new row.
- I thought that from `exeGoogleBatchUpdate()`, I thought that in your script, `auth: await this.getAuth()` in `updateRowsOnSpreadsheet` might not be required to be used.

#### Reference:

- [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help, but actually that does not solve, the same problem kept happening -> add the values of the row on the second row then shifts all the rows below the second row down. But I need the opposite.

Comment: @Hygison Brandao Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested my proposed script, first, a new row is inserted into the 2nd row. And then, a row of `let rowArr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]];` is put to the inserted new row. Isn't this the result you expect? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.